# Change function name in Python

Tags: python

Consider this example:

```py
def foo():
    raise BaseException()

globals()["bar"] = foo
foo.__name__ = "bar"
# foo.__code__.co_name = "bar" # - Error: property is readonly

bar()
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*path*/kar.py", line 9, in <module>
    bar()
  File "*path*/kar.py", line 2, in foo
    raise BaseException()
BaseException
```

How can I change the function name "foo" in the traceback? I already tried `foo.__name__ = "bar"`, `globals()["bar"] = foo` and `foo.__code__.co_name = "bar"`, but while the first two one just do nothing, the third one fails with `AttributeError: readonly attribute`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Changing function traceback name

You want to return a function with a different name within the function you call.

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        raise BaseException
    return bar

bar = foo()

bar()
```

Observe the following traceback:
[image]

Old Answer:
So I'm assuming your goal is to be able to call foo as bar with bar().

I think what you need to do is set the variable name equal to the function you want to call. If you define the variable above a function definition and outside of a function, then that variable is global (it can be used in subsequent function definitions).

See the following code and screenshot.

```
def foo():
    for i in range(1,11):
        print(i)


bar = foo #Store the function in a variable name = be sure not to put parentheses - that tells it to call!

bar() #call the function you stored in a variable name
print(bar) #print the function's location in memory to show that it is stored.
```

Let me know if you are trying to do something differently, or if you are just trying to store a function in a variable to be called later.
[image]

Comment: I would like to change the function name in the traceback or when printed, I believe its the same

Comment: @SuperHrush I have updated the answer so that the function name in the traceback is now bar, I have shown screenshot and code in update as well. Let me know if this is what you want / if you have any questions.

Comment: My main concern is changing function name in traceback using a string during runtime, not an identifier. I'm sorry if I didn't clarify this in my question properly.

Comment: That does not really answers my question, but with the help of this I found what I was looking for.